# Tried to Move Wordpress from Subdirectory to Domain, Site Broke

Tags: wordpress, installation, wordpress-theming, move, subdirectory

I tried to move my beta Wordpress site to my live domain, and now everything's broken. I have no idea how to fix this. Here's what I did:

1. I had a site running at mydomain.com, but I wanted to rebuild it. So I downloaded a new installation of WordPress at mydomain.com/test and built a new theme.
2. I finished the new theme and was ready to move it to mydomain.com. I decided to leave everything in the subdomain for the move, so I followed [these instructions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory).
3. It worked fine. Mydomain.com was displaying the new site.
4. Then, I stupidly decided that I wanted to rename the subdirectory from /test to /v2 (because I wanted a cleaner name and I wanted to leave /test open for testing rather than use it for my new site).
5. Everything broke.
6. I tried to change the subdirectory back to /test because the site was working with that, but everything is still broken. The theme doesn't seem to be loading. My site is not displaying any styles. My photos aren't displaying correctly. My plugins are gone.

Is there any way to fix this?  Please tell me I didn't just lose 3 months of work...

[This is my site](http://mcography.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The database,will have the url set to mydomain.com/test
you will need to update the db entries see below script
http://dan.doezema.com/2010/04/wordpress-domain-change/

Comment: I ran the script as you suggested, but my site is still broken. And now I can't access mydomain.com/wp-admin at all. Other ideas?

Comment: Okay, I went to phpMyAdmin and changed the siteurl back to mydomain.com/test and now I can log in to mydomain.com/wp-admin. But everything is still broken. Help?

Comment: And now the admin dashboard is telling me that my .htaccess file is not writable. Is there any way to fix all of this?

Comment: What are the permissions set to?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to update your `siteurl` and `home` values in your Wordpress Database. Log in to your cPanel and go to phpMyAdmin. From there you should be able to open your WordPress MySQL Database.

Go to your `wp-options` table and make sure that your `siteurl` (option_id 1) and `home` (option_id 37) values are using the correct path ie `http://mcography.com/test`

You may also need to update your permalinks. Even though you don't have to change any options, saving the permalinks again should refresh your .htaccess file.

Comment: I ended up creating a new database, reinstalling Wordpress, reuploading my theme, and starting over. Luckily, I didn't have too much content on the site, so it didn't take too long. Thanks for your suggestion, though.